# Opengl Swapping Shaders

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I am trying to use two separate shader programs for drawing two objects. When running the program only the object using the first shader program is rendered. Additionally, when deleting the first shader after it runs only the second object is rendered.

Code is below. Any help is appreciated.

```
void display()
{   
    mat4 mod, p, v;
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

    //First Shader
    glUseProgram(lightProgram);
    p = perspective(zoom*45.0, aspect, zNear, zFar);
    v = getViewMatrix();
    mod = translate(0.0, 0.0, -5.0);
    GLint objectColorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(lightProgram, "objectColor");
    GLint lightColorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(lightProgram, "lightColor");
    glUniform3f(objectColorLoc, 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.31f);
    glUniform3f(lightColorLoc,  1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

    model = glGetUniformLocation( lightProgram, "model" );
    view = glGetUniformLocation( lightProgram, "view" );
    projection = glGetUniformLocation( lightProgram, "projection" );  
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projection, 1, GL_TRUE, &p.m[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv( view, 1, GL_TRUE, &v.m[0][0] );

    glBindVertexArray(containerVAO);
    glUniformMatrix4fv( model, 1, GL_TRUE, &mod.m[0][0] );
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36 );
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    //glDeleteProgram(lightProgram);

    //Model 2
    //Second Shader
    glUseProgram(lampProgram);
    model = glGetUniformLocation( lampProgram, "model" );
    view = glGetUniformLocation( lampProgram, "view" );
    projection = glGetUniformLocation( lampProgram, "projection" );
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projection, 1, GL_TRUE, &p.m[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv( view, 1, GL_TRUE, &v.m[0][0] );

    mod = translatevec3(lightPos);
    glBindVertexArray (lightVAO);
    glUniformMatrix4fv( model, 1, GL_TRUE, &mod.m[0][0] );
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36 );
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Additionally I am creating my programs using

```
lightProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(lightProgram, lightVertShader);
glAttachShader(lightProgram, lightFragShader);
glLinkProgram(lightProgram);

lampProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(lampProgram, lampVertShader);
glAttachShader(lampProgram, lampFragShader);
glLinkProgram(lampProgram);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you ever call the swap buffers function after each display call? Are you geting any errors in the shader compilation or linking logs?